# How to individual variables from aws_sgw_facts ansible results

Tags: ansible-template

I'm fairly new to ansible and have been trying to set a fact in an ansible script but I'm not sure of the correct syntax for getting information of an element in an array.  I am able to set the **aws_storage_gateway_arn** value but not the **aws_storage_gateway_disk_id** value in the following ansible code:

```
- name: Get AWS storage gateway facts
  aws_sgw_facts:
  register: aws_storage_gateways

- name: Set fact for needed storage gateway arn and disk information
  set_fact: 
         aws_storage_gateway_arn="{{ aws_storage_gateways.gateways | selectattr('gateway_name', 'match', 'storage-gateway-test') | map(attribute='gateway_arn') | list }}"
         aws_storage_gateway_disk_id="{{ aws_storage_gateways.gateways | selectattr('local_disks[]', 'match', 'disk_status') | map(attribute='disk_id') | list}}"
```

The JSON output (account info removed) that I'm working with looks similar to the following:

```
{
   "gateways":[
      {
         "ec2_instance_id":"i-XXXXXXXXXXX",
         "ec2_instance_region":"us-east-1",
         "file_shares":[
            
         ],
         "gateway_arn":"arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:gateway/sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_id":"sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_name":"storage-gateway-test",
         "gateway_operational_state":"ACTIVE",
         "gateway_type":"FILE_S3",
         "local_disks":[
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[
                  
               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd1",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdf",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n1",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can set the **aws_storage_gateway_disk_id** value?

Answer (score 0):

before you select attribute local_disks, you need to selectattr gateway_name.
In the sample, i put more elements on the variable aws_storage_gateways to see if the filters worked.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    aws_storage_gateways: {
   "gateways":[
      {
         "ec2_instance_id":"i-XXXXXXXXXXX",
         "ec2_instance_region":"us-east-1",
         "file_shares":[

         ],
         "gateway_arn":"arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:gateway/sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_id":"sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_name":"storage-gateway-prod",
         "gateway_operational_state":"ACTIVE",
         "gateway_type":"FILE_S3",
         "local_disks":[
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[

               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd1",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdf",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n1",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "ec2_instance_id":"i-XXXXXXXXXXX",
         "ec2_instance_region":"us-east-1",
         "file_shares":[

         ],
         "gateway_arn":"arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:gateway/sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_id":"sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_name":"storage-gateway-test",
         "gateway_operational_state":"ACTIVE",
         "gateway_type":"FILE_S3",
         "local_disks":[
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[

               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd1",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdf",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n1",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            },
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[

               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd2",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdg",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n2",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

  tasks:

    - name: Set fact for needed storage gateway arn and disk information
      set_fact:
        aws_storage_gateway_arn: "{{ aws_storage_gateways.gateways
                                      | selectattr('gateway_name', 'match', 'storage-gateway-test')
                                      | map(attribute='gateway_arn')
                                      | list }}"
        aws_storage_gateway_disk_id: "{{ aws_storage_gateways.gateways
                                          | selectattr('gateway_name', 'match', 'storage-gateway-test')
                                          | map(attribute='local_disks')
                                          | flatten
                                          | list
                                          | selectattr('disk_status', 'match', 'present')
                                          | map(attribute='disk_id')
                                          | list }}"
    - name: DEBUG | aws_storage_gateway_arn
      debug:
        msg: "{{ aws_storage_gateway_arn }}"

    - name: DEBUG | aws_storage_gateway_disk_id
      debug:
        msg: "{{ aws_storage_gateway_disk_id }}"
```

And the output:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [Set fact for needed storage gateway arn and disk information] *******************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [DEBUG | aws_storage_gateway_arn] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:gateway/sgw-XXXXXXXX"
    ]
}

TASK [DEBUG | aws_storage_gateway_disk_id] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd1",
        "0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************
```

The same example with JSON variable:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    aws_storage_gateways: '{
   "gateways":[
      {
         "ec2_instance_id":"i-XXXXXXXXXXX",
         "ec2_instance_region":"us-east-1",
         "file_shares":[

         ],
         "gateway_arn":"arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:gateway/sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_id":"sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_name":"storage-gateway-prod",
         "gateway_operational_state":"ACTIVE",
         "gateway_type":"FILE_S3",
         "local_disks":[
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[

               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd1",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdf",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n1",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "ec2_instance_id":"i-XXXXXXXXXXX",
         "ec2_instance_region":"us-east-1",
         "file_shares":[

         ],
         "gateway_arn":"arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:gateway/sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_id":"sgw-XXXXXXXX",
         "gateway_name":"storage-gateway-test",
         "gateway_operational_state":"ACTIVE",
         "gateway_type":"FILE_S3",
         "local_disks":[
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[

               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd1",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdf",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n1",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            },
            {
               "disk_allocation_type":"AVAILABLE",
               "disk_attribute_list":[

               ],
               "disk_id":"0773a607-2792-4214-86a0-43ba36151bd2",
               "disk_node":"/dev/sdg",
               "disk_path":"/dev/nvme1n2",
               "disk_size_in_bytes":536870912000,
               "disk_status":"present"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}'
  tasks:

    - name: Set fact for needed storage gateway arn and disk information
      set_fact:
        aws_storage_gateway_arn: "{{ aws_storage_gateways
                                      | from_json
                                      | json_query('gateways[*] | [?gateway_name ==`storage-gateway-test`].gateway_arn')
                                      | list }}"
        aws_storage_gateway_disk_id: "{{ aws_storage_gateways
                                          | from_json
                                          | json_query('gateways[*] | [?gateway_name ==`storage-gateway-test`].local_disks[*].disk_id')
                                          | flatten
                                          | list }}"


    - name: DEBUG | aws_storage_gateway_arn
      debug:
        msg: "{{ aws_storage_gateway_arn }}"

    - name: DEBUG | aws_storage_gateway_disk_id
      debug:
        msg: "{{ aws_storage_gateway_disk_id }}"
```